# Ftp Retrieving timestamp of a file

Tags: .net, ftp

I need to get the timestamp of a file on a ftp folder.
Behind, I'm using ftpclient found on codeplex. http://ftpclient.codeplex.com/

Anyway, I tryed 2 ways:

1. GetDateTimestamp command

   ```
   '...
   ftp.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp
   '...
   ```

   I get an error like: remote server error(500) syntax error. Not recognised command..
2. ListDirectoryDetails command

   ```
   '...
   ftp.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
   '...
   ```

   The list of file has the FileDateTime Property set to MinDate.
   Debugging, i've found that it cannot parse a string like 'Dec 24 10:15',
   but it can parse 'Jan 07 10:15' to '#1/7/2013 7:10:00 AM#', which is right on the date part but wrong on time part.

Exploring the ftp folder with windows explorer or filezilla client, i see that 'Last modified' column shows correct value.

Would be accettable for me to download the file with the original Date/time, but with FtpClient library i get something like: The requested URI is not valid for this ftp command.

Again, downloading with windows explorer or filezilla client, original date is preserved (Filezilla has an option to do that).

Comment: How about [downloading FileZilla's source](http://filezilla-project.org/sourcecode.php) code and taking a look, how they do it?

Comment: I can eventually take a look, on the top, filezilla shows sent commands, but enabling preserve timestamps option the sent command seems the same. :)

Comment: I would expect FileZilla having lots of custom parsing code of the received strings into date, possibly even depending on the used FTP _server_ software.

Comment: I tryed looking at filezilla source but i am not comfortable at all with c++. The only thing i've seen it uses MFMT command. But trying to set Method property to 'MFMT' raises an argumentexception, not supported method.

Comment: [This posting](http://forum.rebex.net/questions/2326/get-remote-file-s-timestamp-using-ftps/2327) has some remarks on the date stuff that might help you.